# Open button dropdown programatically, but does something weird to the "caret"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, here is an example of the problem I'm getting:

Here is an example of the problem I'm getting:

http://www.bootply.com/fUELEN22ww

If you click the *down arrow*, it works fine.... but when you trigger it by clicking on **Select Room**, the *down arrow* gets extra wide.

At first I thought maybe I was overwriting a class, but I've managed to get it happening with a fresh install on the above bootply.

I've been going round and round in circles with this one, and I still can't see whats causing it.

Anyone got any suggestions? Basically, I just need the dropdown to open upon clicking on the **Select Room** option)

Thanks!

Comment: Other than your template helper not being parsed (obviously) I don't see any issue here. The arrow doesn't change sizes for me, using latest Chrome.

Comment: No strangeness, using Firefox latest.

Comment: @Christina and below9k - this is in the latest FF, with all add-ons disabled. Schmalzy found a solution for me though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the "Select Room" button, it inserts a `<div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>` element between the two buttons in the `.btn-group`. This causes the CSS rule below to no longer apply to the `.dropdown-toggle` button, because the `.dropdown-toggle` is no longer directly next to a `.btn`. The default 12px of padding is then applied instead of 8px.

```
.btn-group>.btn+.dropdown-toggle {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Adding this rule to your css should resolve the issue.

```
.btn-group>.dropdown-toggle {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: You ledgend @Schmalzy - that did the trick. It was driving me up the wall!